# How to add validation to Multer endpoint

Tags: express, authentication, validation, middleware, multer

I have added an endpoint which uses Multer but I can't seem to add validation as req.body does not seem to be returned. Uploading and authentication works, but the validation doesn't.

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req: Request, file: any, cb: any) => {
        cb(null, "downloads/"); // Set the destination folder for uploaded files
    },
    filename: async (req: Request, file: any, cb: any) => {
        const id = require("crypto").randomUUID();

        // Save to database
        try {
            await new File({
                id,
                version: req.body.version.toLowerCase(),
                type: req.body.type.toLowerCase(),
                uploaded: Date.now()
            }).save()
        } catch (error) {
            return cb(error);
        }

        cb(null, id + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
})

const upload = util.promisify(multer({ storage }).single("file"));;

const validation = async (req: Request & SessionData, res: Response) => {
    // Authentication
    if(!req.session.token) return { status: 401, message: "You are not logged in.", code: "LOGGED_OUT" };
    if(process.env.ownerId !== req.session.user.id) return { status: 401, message: "You are not authorised to use this endpoint.", code: "UNAUTHORISED" };

    // Validation
    if(!req.body.version) return { status: 400, message: "Missing version.", code: "MISSING_VERSION" };
    if(!req.body.type) return { status: 400, message: "Missing type.", code: "MISSING_TYPE" };
    if(!["stable", "latest", "beta", "tester"].includes(req.body.type)) return { status: 400, message: "Invalid type.", code: "INVALID_TYPE" };

    const version = req.body.version.toLowerCase();
    const type = req.body.type.toLowerCase();

    // Check if version already exists
    if(await File.exists({ version, type })) return { status: 400, message: "Version already exists.", code: "VERSION_EXISTS" };

    return false;
}

const apiAdminUpload = async (req: Request & SessionData, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const result = await validation(req, res);

    if(result) return res.status(result.status).json({ message: result.message, code: result.code });

    await upload(req, res);
}

router.post("/api/admin/upload", apiAdminUpload, async (req: Request & SessionData, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    res.json({ message: "File uploaded successfully.", code: "FILE_UPLOADED" });
})
```

I have tried putting validation into a separate function but it didn't work. I did also try manually adding each function separately in the router.post section which also didn't work.

Comment: What are you trying to validate in Multer?